# Conseguir ubicación del usuario en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocalización

Estoy con un problema a la hora de conseguir la ubicacion del usuario en un componente de clase en React. Este es el codigo que tengo por el momento:

```
componentDidMount(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.setState({
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            long: position.coords.longitude
        })
    })
}
```

Pero si ejecuto un console.log(this.state) no muestra las coordenadas. Que podria hacer en este caso? Gracias.

Edit: Si me muestra la lat y long con el console log, pero esto lo tengo que usar para hacer una llamada a una api y no la realiza, agrego el codigo aca abajo:

```
fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=9658158b8c4544859d4194427210410&q=${this.state.lat},${this.state.long}&days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data)
```

Osea la llamada se realiza, pero es como si no hubiera tomado los datos y me da un error en la consola.

Comment: Para que funcione el cliente debe de aceptar que el navegador acceda a su ubicación.

Comment: ¿En que parte ejecutas el `console.log(this.state)`? Compárte la estructura de tu objeto `state`, saludos

Comment: Hice un edit en la pregunta y la corregi, me estaba explicando mal

Comment: Creo que es un problema de tiempos, cuando quieres acceder al `state` aún no ha obtenido la latitud y longitud, recuerda que es un callback entonces el dato no será sesteado hasta tiempo después de que se ejecutó `getCurrentPosition `.